# Second message box

Tags: ms-access, vba, messagebox

This is my first bit of code that I've tried to do myself so please forgive any noob mistakes.

I'm trying to get a second message box to appear if no is selected on the first one but am having no luck. Any help would be great.

code as follows:

```
    Private Sub cmdUploadReady_Click()

Dim Msg, Style, Title, Help, Ctxt, Response, MyString

Msg = "Before Uploading Hole Data you must register you Work Program/POWE. Have you done this?"
Style = vbYesNo + vbCritical
Title = "Uploader"


Response = MsgBox(Msg, Style, Title, Help, Ctxt)

If Response = vbYes Then
'make pickers visible
Me.POWENumber_Label.Visible = True
Me.POWE_picker.Visible = True
Me.cmdUploadHoles.Visible = True


Else

Msg = "MsgBox do you wish to register now?"
        Style = vbYesNo + vbQuestion
        If Response = vbYes Then
        DoCmd.OpenForm "frmWorkPrograms_new"

        Else
        Cancel = True

        End If


End If

End Sub
```

Cheers in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below code. Need to add this line   Response = MsgBox(Msg, Style, Title, Help, Ctxt)

```
  Private Sub cmdUploadReady_Click()

        Dim Msg, Style, Title, Help, Ctxt, Response, MyString

        Msg = "Before Uploading Hole Data you must register you Work Program/POWE. Have you done this?"
        Style = vbYesNo + vbCritical
        Title = "Uploader"


        Response = MsgBox(Msg, Style, Title, Help, Ctxt)

        If Response = vbYes Then
            'make pickers visible
            Me.POWENumber_Label.Visible = True
            Me.POWE_picker.Visible = True
            Me.cmdUploadHoles.Visible = True


        Else

            Msg = "MsgBox do you wish to register now?"
            Style = vbYesNo + vbQuestion
            Response = MsgBox(Msg, Style, Title, Help, Ctxt) '***Add this line****'

            If Response = vbYes Then
                DoCmd.OpenForm "frmWorkPrograms_new"

            Else
                Cancel = True

            End If


        End If
```